# Updated contents of SSRS reports on SP 2013

Tags: reporting-services

hoping you must be fit and fine...
i want to ask one question regarding SQL Server Reporting Services Reports that has been deployed on SP 2013.

i have a BI machine that consists of SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2 native mode and i have deployed my reports on SharePoint 2013. Reports are being displaying fine...but how do i show the reports on SP when the database is updated (when some more records are inserted or deleted)?

Answer (score 2):

Use Report View webpart,

[Add the Report Viewer Web Part to a Web Page (Reporting Services in SharePoint Integrated Mode)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326362.aspx)

You can set webpart's property **Show refresh button** to true, so when a user clicks on refresh button it will update report.

Comment: Thanks Raja for your answer...what else if i have a cube in the Analysis Services? Does that "Refresh Button" will refresh the cube? (As the data is OLAP)